# MySQL monitoring tools

Tags: mysql, monitoring

What tools do you use to monitor the health of your MySQL server instance? Are they for free or commercial?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [MySQL Cacti Templates](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/).

Comment: Upvote for this. I have been using these a while, thanks to Percona and Xarpb.

Comment: These templates are very good - I use them to monitor all our MySQL boxes.

Answer (score 6):

mytop provides some handy CLI info, it's free (*unix only).

Answer (score 2):

Mysql has a free one called [Mysql Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/administrator/en/index.html) which is part of the mysql GUI tools package.

Mysql Administrator connection [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/administrator/en/mysql-gui-options-connections.html).

There is also the Mysql Enterprise Monitor which has many more monitoring features.  You can monitor Mysql on other servers see [faq question 7](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/faq.html#29).

Comment: But MySQL Monitor is just able to monitor local MySQL instances, right? So I wouldn't be able to monitor a MySQL server on a linux machine.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say MySQL Administrator only can monitor local instances.

Comment: No, you can monitor Mysql instances on non-local servers on any OS mysql supports.

Comment: Yes, Mysql Admin can also monitor an MySql instance on another server.
I'll post link in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) for remote administration of mySQL. Nice GUI environment, and there is a free community edition.

This company also makes MONyog, a mySQL monitoring solution, but it's not free and I haven't played with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a custom Zabbix configuration for extracting useful data points from MySQL.  I should get around to opening these scripts up to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from running cacti to graph the mysql performance over time, we have [mysqltuner.com](http://mysqltuner.com) setup to send us a daily report of any variables on the server we should be keeping an eye on.

Answer (score 1):

`innotop` has been fantastic for monitoring. i believe its recommended in both editions of `high performance mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

As basic as it is, I've used:

```
$ watch -n1 "mysqladmin processlist -u root -pYouWillNeverGuessThis"
```

This provides me with a list of connections, users, hosts, databases, commands etc, updated every second. It's a real-time "who's doing what right now?" solution.

Very simple, but also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use a cronjob running every 5 minutes with `mysqladmin processlist`. See also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/418/how-do-you-track-and-debug-mysql-performance-issues) .

In addition, [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) has some monitoring features.

Answer (score 0):

We use [hyperic](http://hyperic-hq.sourceforge.net/), it is an open source application, but there is a commercial product as well if you want. It also monitors the operating system, web servers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to monitor the underlying platform. I would monitor

- IOPS on the log, data and tmp devices (you do have those on three seperate LUNs don't you ?)
- Swapping (more than a few pages / second is bad for mysql, google "mysql swappiness" to find out why)
- Memory statistics for the host OS. A general rule of thumb I follow is to allocate no more than 80% to the mysql process to leave some room for the OS and the buffer cache

You can use SNMP and Cacti to monitor all of these things

Answer (score 0):

mtop is great for monitoring current running queries and system variables.

Answer (score 0):

Cacti, as mentioned above. Also mytop sometimes to monitor current activity.

Answer (score 0):

Basic monitoring via the [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) nagios_mysql plugin, added a small custom script to monitor slaves status and slavelag.

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly monitoring but you can use mysqlreport to have a good overview of how well your mysql server is performing and if it is properly configured.

http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the database(s) that is running on the sever.

I usually check for the

- number of queries

  - depending on database
- indexes
- slow query log
- mysqlping
- mysql connection from a remote host to a certain database

  - check that it works from the right hosts
  - check that it fails from the right hosts
- select the current time to be sure it's correct
- select for collations/encodings
- connected users

on the framework side I'm using munin for everything that could give me metrics and nagios (soon to be [icinga](http://www.icinga.org)) for everything that gives me status information.

Answer (score 0):

For more comprehensive monitoring of MySQL (but commercial, so only if your database is worth it) check out www.LogicMonitor.com. No configuration required (detects storage engine types, replication status, etc); provides tuning recommendations; full historical graphing and alerting in one system; very extensible, and will monitor the rest of your datacenter infrastructure.